# Do lions crabwalk?

Tags: zoology, ethology, feline

Cats turn sideways arch their back and puff their fur, to apppear bigger, when trying to intimidate someone. Do lions do that? What is the largest feline that does that?

Comment: As apex predators who can also run away if necessary, it would seem to be an unnecessary tactic.

Comment: with a mane turning sideways might actually make you look smaller.